# -Fallback: true causes meta tags not to be in source

Tags: next.js, seo

A Copy of an issue I opened - Seeing a strange behaviour when using fallback: true, have followed all the documentation regarding fetching data int he getStaticProps method and even using hardcoded value the result is the same. When using fallback: true, locally when the page loads the meta description and title appear in the elements of the console, but inspecting the source they are not present. Where as using fallback: 'blocking' the meta description and title is present in both elements and the source. On our deployed version, the behaviour is slightly different, the first time the page is generated, the meta description and title are missing from the source, however refreshing the page they then become present. Im not 100% if this is an issue or just the way it was working but our SEO team are complaining that title and meta descriptions are missing, testing this with a variety for online crawlers, some seem to pick up the title and description without any problems and others say they are missing

forked an app and created an [example app](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-blocking-nonblocking-meta-ofu27z) where this can be clearly seen selected the fallback: true page and the title and description are missing, use the fallback: blocking route and both can be found in the source as expected.

Has anyone encountered the same, does this actually affect the seo scoring?

example of page using blocking method:

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import { fetchImportantProductIds, fetchProduct } from "../../api";

export default function NonBlockingProduct({ product }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{product.id}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={product.description} />
      </Head>
      <div>
        <h1>Product number {product.id}</h1>
        <p>{product.description}</p>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const importantProductIds = await fetchImportantProductIds();

  return {
    paths: importantProductIds.map((id) => ({ params: { id } })),
    fallback: "blocking"
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const product = await fetchProduct(params.id);

  return { props: { product } };
}
```

example of non-blocking option :

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { fetchImportantProductIds, fetchProduct } from "../../api";

export default function NonBlockingProduct({ product }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{product.id}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={product.description} />
      </Head>
      <div>
        <h1>Product number {product.id}</h1>
        <p>{product.description}</p>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const importantProductIds = await fetchImportantProductIds();

  return {
    paths: importantProductIds.map((id) => ({ params: { id } })),
    fallback: true
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const product = await fetchProduct(params.id);

  return { props: { product } };
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: the link is to a working example in codebox, who does one reproduce a next app within stackoverflow? @Rob

Comment: You can retain the link but you must post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

I had an answer back from next that the behaviour is expected and that for crawlers they will receive the page the same as using the blocking method

> This is expected behavior. fallback: true serves a statically generated If you want all requests to hold the fully generated HTML you can use fallback: 'blocking'. Crawlers get the fallback: 'blocking' behavior in all cases. Please see the documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true